# Consing lists with user-defined type in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types, user-defined-types

I have this type I defined myself:

```
data Item =
Book String String String Int     -- Title, Author, Year, Qty
| Movie String String String Int  -- Title, Director, Year, Qty
    | CD String String String Int deriving Show  -- Title, Artist, Year, Qty
```

I've created an empty list

```
all_Items = []
```

With the following function I am trying to insert a new book of type Item (Book) into the all_Items

```
addBook all_Items = do
    putStrLn "Enter the title of the book"
    tit <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter the author of the book"
    aut <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter the year this book was published"
    yr <- getLine
    putStrLn "Enter quantity of copies for this item in the inventory"
    qty <- getLine
    Book tit aut yr (read qty::Int):all_Items
    return(all_Items)
```

I however am receiving this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' with actual type `[a1]'
```

The error points to the line where I am using the consing operator to add the new book to the list. I can gather that it is a type error but I can't figure out what it is that I am doing wrong and how to fix it. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: In Haskell you can't re-define the value of a variable. You might want to try one of the "standard" books for learning Haskell: http://learnyouahaskell.com/ or http://book.realworldhaskell.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
    Book tit aut yr (read qty::Int):all_Items
```

takes your existing list `all_Items`, and a new `Item` value, and *makes a new list* consisting of the new `Item` value and all the items in `all_Items`. *It does not modify* `all_Items`.

But that's not what the error message is about.

The line is in a do-block that does i/o. Each statement must be either an expression of type `IO something` (possibly binding the `something` value to a variable), or a let statement.

Whereas this line

```
    Book tit aut yr (read qty::Int):all_Items
```

is an expression of type `[Item]`. But an `IO something` was expected, hence the error.

**How to fix these errors:** replace the last two lines of the do-block with

```
    return (Book tit aut yr (read qty::Int):all_Items)
```

**Also note**

- You have

  ```
  all_Items = []
  ```

  and

  ```
  addBook all_Items = do
  ```

  In the first case `all_Items` is a top level value. In the second case it is the parameter to the `addBook` function. They are different things.
- You already told Haskell that the fourth argument to the `Book` constructor is an `Int`. You don't need to repeat yourself. So the last line of `addBook` can be

  ```
      return (Book tit aut yr (read qty) : all_Items)
  ```

Comment: I tried redefining all_Items type to [Item]          
    all_Items:: [Item]
    all=Items:: []         

and this worked, is it just compiling but will it give me something I am not expecting?
On another note, how would I fix what you first mentioned. So that the consing will modify my original all_Items

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer: it fixes both these issues. It does not modify the original value, but the value returned from the function will contain the extra item. In Haskell values are immutable and do not change. On your first point, I don't understand what you've tried.

Comment: Oh ok, and on my first point never mind I realized that what I was doing was basically what you recommended so my solutions was not really a solution. Again thanks so much for you help :)